# Add colour schema to old quesions on main SE sites

Tags: discussion

This question is inspired by [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7195/101265) discussion which is about close the old questions and not display them at all. For me closing questions (old ones) is too much. At the end the idea of SE (by my understanding) is to collect and make available solutions in form of question/answer(s)

Instead of closing/not displaying at all the old questions maybe SE devs can just add different colour schema for such old questions. This will help distinguish them, decrease the frustration of visitors, reading/commenting/answering quite old questions and leave only visitors which are happy to answer such question (even if they do not get much visibility and votes for this act).

Of course I do not expect to see such question in negative colour view but just slight darker (for example) colour. Devs for sure will keep in mind the differences must be distinguishable for colour blind people.

So one line summary: **what is your opinion of "colouring"old questions on main page of each SE site?**

Comment: Thank you, Romeo. I really hope this will make it.

Comment: @paladin, let see. The question is for discussion, to be deployed (if accepted) may take a long way :)